# Derive a transformation matrix that mirrors the image over a line passing through the origin with angle $\phi$ to the $x$-axis.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Using homogeneous coordinates, derive a $3$x$3$ transformation matrix $M$ that mirrors an image over a line passing through the origin, with angle $\phi$ to the $x$-axis.

**Comment:** This is from an old exam in computer graphics. I don't remember how we did this back in linear algebra so I'd be grateful if someone could show me the steps. If you don't know what "homogeneous coordinates" means, pay no attention to it, a $2$x$2$ transformation matrix without homogenous coordinates would suffice and I can do the rest.

Comment: Take the 3 standard basis vectors, mirror them across the line, and stick the results together to form a matrix.

Comment: @user2357112 Sounds good, but how do I mirror, say, (1,0,0) through this line? (Now we are doing this in three-dimensions when the problem asks for two, but it makes no difference to me since I want to know the general method.)

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in the general n-dimensional case. I might be able to figure out the 3-dimensional case if I thought about it for a while, but off the top of my head, I don't know how to do it. For reflection across a plane or hyperplane, you can use a [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation); I didn't know that one either, but I found it on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to think about rotating the plane $-\phi$ degrees, so that the desired line of reflection is now the $x$-axis, then reflect over the $x$-axis, then rotate back by $\phi$ degrees.

How do we do it?  Recall the "rotation by $\phi$" matrix \begin{equation*}R_{\phi} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)\end{pmatrix},\end{equation*}
and the "reflect over the $x$-axis" matrix
\begin{equation*} Refl_x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.\end{equation*}

Then the "reflect across angle $\phi$" matrix $Refl_{\phi}$ is calculated as we described above:
\begin{eqnarray*}Refl_{\phi} &=& R_{\phi}\cdot Refl_x \cdot R_{-\phi} \\
&=& \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(-\phi) & -\sin(-\phi) \\ \sin(-\phi) & \cos(-\phi)\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) \\ -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)\end{pmatrix} \\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2(\phi)-\sin^2(\phi) & 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \\ 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)& \sin^2(\phi)-\cos^2(\phi)\end{pmatrix} \\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\phi) & \sin(2\phi) \\ \sin(2\phi) & -\cos(2\phi)\end{pmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a very intuitive method that can easily be generalized to $n$-dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If vector $A$ is reflected across vector $B$ to create vector $C$,

- The  midpoint of $A$ and $C$ is along $B$:
  $C + (A - C)/2 \in kB$, so $A + C \in kB$
- Length is preserved: $|A| = |C|$

Your $B$ vector is $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$

First consider the x-axis unit: $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ translates to $f(e_1) =  \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = k\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{cases} a + 1 = k \cos(\phi) \\
                b = k \sin(\phi) \\
                a^2 + b^2 = 1 \quad \text{(because length is preserved)}
\end{cases}$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\begin{cases} k = 2\cos(\phi) \\
 a = 2\cos(\phi)^2 - 1 \\
 b = 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)
\end{cases}$$

Same for the y-unit $e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ translates to $f(e_2) =  \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = k\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{cases} c = k \cos(\phi) \\
                d + 1 = k \sin(\phi) \\
                c^2 + d^2 = 1 \quad \text{(again because length is preserved)}
\end{cases}$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\begin{cases} k = 2\sin(\phi) \\
 c = 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \\
 d = 2\sin(\phi)^2 - 1
\end{cases}$$

Since we know that $f(v) = f(xe_1 + ye_2) = xf(e_1) + yf(e_2)$, it follows:

$$\begin{align}
f\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\right) &= \begin{bmatrix} 2\cos(\phi)^2 - 1 & 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \\ 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) & 2\sin(\phi)^2 - 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2\phi) & \sin(2\phi) \\ \sin(2\phi) & -\cos(2\phi)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! I notice though that @ChocolateAndCheese reaches a seemingly different answer by following another method. Do you have any idea how that can be?

Comment: They are the same except that I accidentally didn't type out a factor of $2$ on the $k$, I updated to show.  It's just double angle formulas: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: The reason I like the above approach better is that it generalizes to arbitrary choices of vector $B$, but the other answer is simpler for rotations within a plane.